# Converting .vox audio files to .wav or .mp3 with NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am trying to convert .vox to .mp3 or .wav with `NAudio` with the code below:-

```
var bytes = GetBytes(new FileInfo(@"D:\path\to\vox-file.vox"));

using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(@"D:\path\to\wav-file.wav", new WaveFormat(8000, 8, 2)))
{
    writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

However the converted `.wav` file I am getting has very distorted audio and its not listenable. Am I missing some configuration with `NAudio`?

Comment: Do you see something in the documentation that would lead you to believe NAudio works with `.vox` files?

Comment: @BinaryPatrick I saw a few similar questions on SO where the author of NAudio mentioned its possible because of which I trying to use NAudio for this conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to convert .vox files to .wav with the following:-

```
var bytes = GetBytes(new FileInfo(@"path-to.vox"));

using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(@"path-to.wav", Mp3WaveFormat.CreateMuLawFormat(8000, 1)))
{
    writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

The important bit here is this part: `Mp3WaveFormat.CreateMuLawFormat(8000, 1)`, this is basically some kind of format/configuration for the .wav file which you want to be created and these values may vary depending upon your .vox files